# Cohort Analysis in SQL while recounting users

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to create a cohort query using SQL.
Usually with cohort analysis we look at users and check if a user who performed a specific action at a specific time and count if that user performs the same action over time.

```
WITH by_week
AS (SELECT
  user_id,
  TD_DATE_TRUNC('week', login_time) AS login_week
FROM logins
GROUP BY 1, 2),
with_first_week
AS (SELECT
  user_id,
  login_week,
  FIRST_VALUE(login_week) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY login_week) AS first_week
FROM by_week),
with_week_number
AS (SELECT
  user_id,
  login_week,
  first_week,
  (login_week - first_week) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 7) AS week_number
FROM with_first_week)
SELECT
  TD_TIME_FORMAT(first_week, 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS first_week,
  SUM(CASE WHEN week_number = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN week_number = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN week_number = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_3,
  SUM(CASE WHEN week_number = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_4,
  SUM(CASE WHEN week_number = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_5,
  SUM(CASE WHEN week_number = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_6,
  SUM(CASE WHEN week_number = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_7,
  SUM(CASE WHEN week_number = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_8,
  SUM(CASE WHEN week_number = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_9
FROM with_week_number
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

But let say now I don't care that much about first time/user-level analysis and I only want to see if my login action increases over time (i.e I want to add up logins of the first cohort during week 2 with logins of the second cohort in week 1). Is there a simple/elegant way to do this?

Edit:

Giving an example below

```
WeekStart     Week1              Week2          Week 3
2017/05/03     66                **53**         **49**
2017/05/10  (**53**+74)        (**49**+70)      **65**
2017/05/17  (**49**+ 70 + 45)   (**65** + 80)     etc.
```

Comment: I'm using Redshift

Comment: I don't quite understand but maybe this will prompt more explanation: Whats wrong with `SUM(CASE WHEN week_number IN (1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_1and2`. It's usually a good idea to post a sample of what you have and what you want.

Comment: then it's probably not the cohort analysis... *I want to add up logins of the first cohort during week 2 with logins of the second cohort in week 1* translates to removing cohorts, doesn't it? just grouping login times by week from whichever cohort they are

Comment: @AlexYes Yes I guess you are correct ! Still not sure how to do this though :)

Comment: @user2475110 gotcha. posted a suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to group by `login_week` instead of `first_week` so you count all logins during the given week in every row, not by cohort, and then you have to use `>=` instead of `=` so it will sum up this week's cohort with all older cohorts in any given row.

```
WITH 
by_week AS (
    SELECT
    user_id,
    TD_DATE_TRUNC('week', login_time) AS login_week
    FROM logins
    GROUP BY 1, 2
)
,with_first_week AS (
    SELECT
    user_id,
    login_week,
    FIRST_VALUE(login_week) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY login_week) AS first_week
    FROM by_week
)
,with_week_number AS (
    SELECT
    user_id,
    login_week,
    first_week,
    (login_week - first_week) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 7) AS week_number
    FROM with_first_week
)
SELECT
TD_TIME_FORMAT(login_week, 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS login_week,
SUM(CASE WHEN week_number>= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_1,
SUM(CASE WHEN week_number>= 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_2,
SUM(CASE WHEN week_number>= 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_3,
SUM(CASE WHEN week_number>= 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_4,
SUM(CASE WHEN week_number>= 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_5,
SUM(CASE WHEN week_number>= 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_6,
SUM(CASE WHEN week_number>= 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_7,
SUM(CASE WHEN week_number>= 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_8,
SUM(CASE WHEN week_number>= 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS week_9
FROM with_week_number
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: Exactly it! Thanks @AlexYes